# How to change this TRUE or FALSE value on Run time Paticular time

Tags: java, android

I want to change the value of `ENABLE_ADSENSE`  true or false by runtime.when some function using time.

if one function clicked false to change 15Minutes to stay and then it to return as true.

```
public static boolean ENABLE_ADSENSE = true;
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your question? Can you provide more code? Right now, this is just a boolean, but how to you try to change it? Can you provide the methods, that will change the boolean?

Comment: when the video Reward ads is seen after it want to change as false for particular time..

Comment: Then you should have a method, that registers, that the "video reward ad" was shown. Set ENABLE_ADSENSE to false and then shedule a job. That job should fire once after 15 minutes and all it does it ENABLE_ADSENSE=true

Comment: Yes this is am asking..

Answer (score 0):

You can use WorkManager to easily schedule work every 15 min.
I would also suggest using [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences) to store your ENABLE_ADSENSE boolean so you can use it later when you need the check.

First you need is a Worker class:

```
public class MyWorker extends Worker {
    @Override
    public Worker.WorkerResult doWork() {

        // set ENABLE_ADSENSE here

        // Indicate success or failure with your return value:
        return WorkerResult.SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

And to start it every 15 minutes just use:

```
 PeriodicWorkRequest periodicWork = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(MyWorker.class, 15, TimeUnit.Minutes)
                                   .build();
 WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(periodicWork);
```

Don't forget to change ENABLE_ADSENSE=false when you show the video ad.

Comment: am can't understand this?

Comment: But if you run it as peridoic worker, doesn't that mean, it could happen, that the video is shown just 1 or 2 minutes later, as the boolean flag is set back to `true`, because the worker just fired then? My idea would be to create a new singe shot worker, everytime, a video has been watched, to ensure the 15 minutes delay until the next video.